# How to pass a string list to putStr

Tags: haskell, monads

How can a output a list of strings using putStr and map? I want to do something like:

```
s=["test1","test2"]
map putStr s
```

But have no experience with monads and don't know how to get it right...

Any kind of hint is enormously welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of [`map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v%3amap) is:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

this means that, since [`putStr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v%3aputStr) returns an `IO ()`, your expression will return a `[IO ()]`.

You can, instead, use [`mapM_`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v%3amapM-95-) (imported from `Prelude`) that will ignore the return type from the mapping and return an `IO ()` which is a suitable return type for `main`:

```
main = do
    let s=["test1","test2"]
    mapM_ putStr s
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7cce0576b7f49476)

Answer (score 7):

The correct thing to do here is use `mapM_ :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m ()`. But if you'd like to learn a little about some useful `Prelude` functions...

We have two functions here,

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
putStr :: String -> IO ()
```

if we substitute the type of `putStr` into `map` (ie. `a ~ String`, `b ~ IO ()`) we get

```
map putStr :: [String] -> [IO ()]
```

so this takes a list of strings and gives us a list of `IO ()` actions; `IO` computations that don't return anything usefull.

We'd like to turn that `[IO ()]` into something like `IO (...)` because we need `IO` to be the outermost layer in order to use it in `main :: IO ()`

The function `sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]` from the `Prelude` is exactly what we need. It takes a list of monadic actions, executes them and returns the results in a list wrapped in the monad. Intuitively it moves the monad to the outermost layer.

```
sequence . map putStr :: [String] -> IO [()]
```

This is quite close, but we still have `IO [()]` instead of `IO ()`, we don't really care about the `[()]` result and it'd be nice to ignore it. Again, the `Prelude` has what we need: `sequence_ :: Monad m => [m a] -> m ()` which executes each monadic action in the list and ignores their return values.

Note that `mapM_` is defined as

```
mapM_ f = sequence_ . map f
```